# Not able to create symbolik link in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm

```
mahima@INPUNML4JJ8043:/usr/bin$ npm -v
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
```

when I try to create symbolik link it is giving error.

```
mahima@INPUNML4JJ8043:/usr/bin$ ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/node': File exists
```

when I try to install npm or nodejs it says its already installed. I dont know what is the issue.

```
mahima@INPUNML4JJ8043:/usr/bin$ sudo apt-get install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
npm is already the newest version (6.14.4+ds-1ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 80 not upgraded.
```

when I install nodejs

```
mahima@INPUNML4JJ8043:/usr/bin$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (10.19.0~dfsg-3ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 80 not upgraded.
```

what is the issue with my machine. yetereday I did some mistake when trying to upgrade `node` version. now nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

First try to debug the "File exists" report. Try `ls -l /usr/bin/node` and to see what the file is. After you eplore the details, you can eventually delete that file. Second, you usually can not in Ubuntu to make links in system directories with just user permissions. Try `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`. Of course when no file `/usr/bin/node` exists.